# Setting up widget button for performing background job

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to create an app widget that, when pressed, triggers a background job that saves time+location to a database.

From what I have been able to gather so far, the setup I probably want consists of an AppWidgetProvider subclass whose onUpdate() is responsible for setting up a PendingIntent on a RemoteView representing the widget button. Its onReceive() method would catch the broadcast from the PendingIntent, and I would perhaps start off a service from here to perform the background job.

If I'm on the right track so far, I have one challenge, which is that onUpdate() is not triggered on adding the app widget to the desktop, and thus the widget button is not getting set up properly (it ends up doind nothing). Do I have to set the widget up with a configurationactivity, which in turn triggers AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate(), or is there a simpler solution to this?

If I'm not on the right track at all, any pointers to a better way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve would be very much appreciated. :)

**Update:**

Thought I might post some of the code here as well. Here is the receiver definition from the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.QuickAddWidgetProvider" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
             android:resource="@xml/quickadd_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

This is my resource file, defining the widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/quickadd_widget"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0">
</appwidget-provider>
```

This is QuickAddWidgetProvider:

```
public class QuickAddWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("QuickAdd", "onReceive()"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.v("QuickAdd", "onUpdate()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm on the right track so far

Yes!

> I have one challenge, which is that onUpdate() is not triggered on adding the app widget to the desktop, and thus the widget button is not getting set up properly (it ends up doind nothing)

Well, it should. Make sure your `AppWidgetProvider`'s entry in the manifest has the right `<intent-filter>` to receive updates:

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidget" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_provider"/>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just can't see anything wrong with my intent filter. I updated my question with the code in question, maybe another pair of eyes will be able to spot the error. For the record, I can see from the logs that onReceive() is being triggered. Thought it might be related to updatePeriodMillis being set to 0, but changing this does not yield an onUpdate() call either.

Comment: Oh, btw.. if the intent filter is not set up correctly, I don't think I'd be able to get at the widget through the widget menu at all.

Comment: @rogerkk: Well, `onUpdate()` will never be called with your current implementation, as you are blocking it by not chaining to the superclass in `onRecieve()`. Also, AFAIK, the widget menu is driven by the metadata, not the intent filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding the chaining solved my problem! \*facepalm\*. Love your Android books, btw. Cheers!